# Session duplicate entry

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I get the following issue

[image: error]

I can't seem to really duplicate the error because it happens randomly.
But i think this happens when i use chrome and internet explorer to view the website.
In my database it sometimes then updates all the session records with the new 'last_activity'

Searched the web and github for similar problems but did not find anything.

I am using the develop branch

Comment: I know it is too much to ask for dev sql server to completely mirror production but could you please tell more why you think this detail specifically matters here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query is telling the DB to update ALL rows and session id will be unique.

It should be

```
UPDATE xxx SET `last_activity` = 1234 WHERE `session_id` = 'yoursessid'
```

Notice the WHERE clause. and obviously 1234 is your timestamp and yoursessid is the actual session string